# Change / move zendesk help button

Tags: zendesk

actually how can i change the right 'help' zendesk button
to my custom header or footer 'help' button, i need the trigger like even onclick on js,

Kindly advice

Thanks

Warmly

Answer (score 0):

Try the below URL, it should guide you through the process, then just add the part that helped to this thread as URls can change.

https://support.zendesk.com/entries/22618341-Customizing-the-Help-Center

Answer (score 0):

To hide the help button put this behind your zendesk code:

```
zE(function() {
  zE.hide();
});
```

Followed by an `onclick="zE.activate({hideOnClose: true});"` on your contact button.

See: https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/widget/api